# Jmeter Getting Connection Error with MongoDb

Tags: groovy, jmeter, jmeter-5.0, jsr223

I want to perform load test on my mongodb database.So I added mongodb driver to bin/ext folder and restarted jmeter. I selected JSR223 Sampler and selected groovy as my language and added connection code as below

```
import com.mongodb.*

import com.mongodb.client.MongoClients;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings;
import com.mongodb.ServerAddress;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;

import org.bson.Document;

import java.util.Arrays;

try {
    MongoClientSettings settings = MongoClientSettings.builder()
        .applyToClusterSettings {builder -> 
            builder.hosts(Arrays.asList(new ServerAddress(vars.get("mongoHost"),vars.get("mongoPort").toInteger())))}
        .build();

    MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create(settings);

    MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase(vars.get("databaseName"));
    MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection(vars.get("collectionName"));

    vars.putObject("collection", collection);

    return "Connected to " + vars.get("collectionName");
}
catch (Exception e) {
    SampleResult.setSuccessful(false);
    SampleResult.setResponseCode("500");
    SampleResult.setResponseMessage("Exception: " + e);
}
```

mongoHost,mongoPort,databaseName,collectionName are configured in user defined variables(Test Plan).
When I run sampler getting error

```
Thread Name:myThread Group 1-1
Sample Start:2020-01-27 15:57:35 IST
Load time:39
Connect Time:0
Latency:0
Size in bytes:0
Sent bytes:0
Headers size in bytes:0
Body size in bytes:0
Sample Count:1
Error Count:1
Data type ("text"|"bin"|""):text
Response code:500
Response message:javax.script.ScriptException: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Script3.groovy: 6: unable to resolve class com.mongodb.ServerAddress
 @ line 6, column 1.
   import com.mongodb.ServerAddress;
   ^

Script3.groovy: 5: unable to resolve class com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings
 @ line 5, column 1.
   import com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings;
   ^

Script3.groovy: 10: unable to resolve class org.bson.Document
 @ line 10, column 1.
   import org.bson.Document;
   ^

3 errors



SampleResult fields:
ContentType: 
DataEncoding: null
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the following libraries to [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath):

1. [mongo-java-driver](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/mongo-java-driver)
2. [bson](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/bson)

The libraries version must match (or at least be compatible) with your MongoDB version, it can be obtained by running [`db.version()` query](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.version/) in the MongoDB shell

**JMeter restart will be required to pick up the libraries**

More information: [MongoDB Performance Testing with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/mongodb-performance-testing-with-jmeter/)

Comment: I updated mongo-java driver version and added bson library connection is establishing  but getting unauthorized error while reading and inserting.

Comment: Response code:500
Response message:Exception: com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 13 (Unauthorized): 'command insert requires authentication' on server xx.xxx.xx.xxx:27017. The full response is {"operationTime": {"$timestamp": {"t": 1580126230, "i": 1}}, "ok": 0.0, "errmsg": "command insert requires authentication", "code": 13, "codeName": "Unauthorized", "$clusterTime": {"clusterTime": {"$timestamp": {"t": 1580126230, "i": 1}}, "signature": {"hash": {"$binary": "j7ylgmDSaPsZQRX/SwPTo4ZSTII=", "$type": "00"}, "keyId": {"$numberLong": "6785074748788310018"}}}}

Comment: You need to instantiate [MongoCredential](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.6/javadoc/?com/mongodb/MongoCredential.html) like `MongoCredential credential =
            MongoCredential.createCredential("mongoUser", "userDB", "password".toCharArray());` and pass it to the MongoClient initialization line

Comment: I configured like that only.

Comment: If I configure like this MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create("mongodb://user:password@xx.xxx.xx.xxx:27017/?authSource=mysyt&ssl=true");

Comment: Response message:Exception: com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=xx.xxx.xx.xxx:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketWriteException: Exception sending message}, caused by {javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake}, caused by {java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly}}]

Comment: You're asking 10 different questions which are not related to the original question and I cannot provide the answers due to being offtopic and to comment field limitation, consider asking a new question and provide as much information as you can so we could reproduce your issue or at least get understanding what it is about. If my answer is helpful you can accept it